# Purge contacts information on Mac

Tags: macos, contacts, contacts.app

Last month, for a temporary event, I've added a Polish number (+48 prefix) to 800 of my regular contacts using a vCard file.

Now, this event is finished and now I'd like to remove all those temporary polish numbers from my contacts and keep all other information intact.

Is there a way to easily do that, for example, using an Automator action?

Comment: You say you used a vCard to add the "+48 prefix" to the numbers. Can you show an example of a number from the vCard that had been modified?  Does it look like `+481234567890` or _what_ in the vCard?

Comment: Numbers are like +48 697 107 394

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've deleted my original answer because I initially misunderstood how the `+48` numbers were added, sorry about that.

Instead of using AppleScript, I'm going to offer you a different solution because while I could and did modify the original AppleScript *code* to delete the entire number that had a `+48` prefix, nonetheless there were errors that stopped the *script* from executing completely during the testing phase. So I'm opting for a different solution over debugging the AppleScript *code*.

This solution requires exporting the entire contents of the Contacts.app to a vCard file (.vcf), modifying it using a RegEx in `sed`, and then importing the modified vCard file (.vcf) back into Contacts. Note that this method will replace all existing contacts with the updated new *allcontacts.vcf* file and should not be an issue as it's really only removing the information you stated you wanted removed, just in a roundabout way.

NOTE: These directions were tested under OS X 10.11.5 with the Contacts.app using its *default* preferences.

- Open Contacts.
- Backup Contacts, click: File > Export > Contacts Archive…

Now that Contacts have been backed up, do the following...

- Select the first contact and then press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to select all contacts.
- Click: File > Export > Export vCard…
- In the Save As dialog box it will show as, *the name of the first contact and n others*, 
   change it to: *allcontacts*
- Copy and paste the following *command* into Terminal, then press the Space bar to add a *space* afterwards.

  `sed -i.bak -E '/^TEL.*\+48.*$/d'`
- From Finder, drag and drop the *allcontacts.vcf* file onto the Terminal window. Note that in Finder, the *.vcf* extension may be hidden and it will show in Terminal.

Example: `sed -i.bak -E '/^TEL.*\+48.*$/d' /Users/me/Documents/allcontacts.vcf`

- Now press <kbd>enter</kbd> to modify the *allcontacts.vcf* file. A backup of the original is created as: *allcontacts.vcf.bak*

Now import the updated *allcontacts.vcf* file into Contacts.

- File > Import and select the *allcontacts.vcf* file, then click Open.
- On the "Are you sure you want to import n cards?" *sheet* click: Review Duplicates…
- On the ensuing *sheet* select Keep New and check the Apply to All checkbox then click Import.

The Contacts telephone entries containing numbers with a `+48` prefix have been removed.

---

The target lines in the *allcontacts.vcf* file will have the following pattern and note the example below is not the only way it can present and thus the need to use a RegEx aside from the phone numbers themselves being different as the *value* for `type=` can vary too.

Example line in the vCard file: `TEL;type=CELL;type=VOICE:+48 697 107 394`

The RegEx is: `^TEL.*\+48.*$`

Explanation:

- ^ assert position at start of the string.
- TEL matches the characters TEL literally (case sensitive).
- .* matches any character (except newline). Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy].
- \+ matches the character + literally.
- 48 matches the characters 48 literally.
- .* matches any character (except newline). Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy].
- $ assert position at end of the string.

So, the `sed` *command*, `sed -i.bak -E '/^TEL.*\+48.*$/d' file` backups the *file* (`-i.bak`) and deletes any line starting with `TEL` that contains `+48`. Which based on how lines are stored in the vCard will just remove the lines needed to accomplish the task as lines starting with `TEL` that have `+48` in them can only be the lines you want removed.

**NOTE:** The also assumes you did not previously have any numbers with the `+48` prefix before you updated your Contacts with the original vCard file that contained the numbers with the `+48` prefix.

Comment: I think we're almost there. In fact, I don't want just to remove the `+48` prefix but the entire number. I just want to purge the +48 numbers from my contacts.

Comment: @LuCouto, Finally had some time to look back and have updated my answer with a method that while not AppleScript nonetheless it will work.

Comment: Those instructions are very clear and they've worked great! Thanks a lot!